# Use of JasperReports Server to generate a report

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to use jasper report server in a project of college university.

Requirement of user is that he want a link on jsp so that he can generate report according to his needs,can it possible that user generate report . can we gave him a view of tables so that he can generate reports by getting fields from table view.

Please provide me solution to this problem. i want to use JSR.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is doable. You may want to refer to JasperReports-Server-User-Guide Adhoc Reports Section.
Give a link to jasper on your jsp.
Through Adhoc facility i.e, topics, domains or olaps you can expose the required fields or tables from which reports can be generated in adhoc.